# Selecionar data AM - PM TimePicker Android

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Tenho um TimePickerDialog configurado em meu projeto e está funcionando corretamente.

Ao escolher o horário tenho a seguinte opção - PM ou AM.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
private void timePicker(){
        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                        mHour = hourOfDay;
                        mMinute = minute;

                        mHoraString = (hourOfDay + ":" + minute).toString();
                        mHora.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

                        /*milisegundos*/
                        long horaMil = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hourOfDay);
                        long minMil = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minute);

                        long soma_mils = horaMil + minMil;

                        mHoraMilisegundos = Long.toString(soma_mils);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Funciona certinho.

Teria alguma forma mais simples ou como geralmente é utilizado esse recurso, para **SIMPLIFICAR ou deixar mais EXPLICITO** ao usuário se ele quer escolher um horário antes do Meio Dia ou Depois?

Comment: É requisito obrigatório exibir o am/pm? Não pode exibir o relógio no formato 24h?

Comment: Atualmente eu mostro também no formato 24horas. A questão é se teria alguma forma mais amigável para o usuário. @LeonardoLima1

Comment: Atualmente eu mostro também no formato 24horas. A questão é se teria alguma forma mais amigável para o usuário. @LeonardoLima1